# Unable to access methods of WebDriver class when the WebDriver instance is passed to test class from conftest.py (Python + Selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, frameworks, pytest

I am tying to develop my first Selenium framework in Python using Pytest.

Since we should not have set up and tear down methods repeated in all test classes, it is suggested that we declare them as fixture(s) in conftest.py.

Now, I have a fixture method in conftest.py (as shown in the screenshot) and the driver object reference is passed to TestDemo class (other screenshot).

My question is, when we use `driver.`, we get suggestions of all methods, which is very user friendly.

But when I am trying to access the same under TestDemo  class using `self.driver.`, the methods are not visible.

Interestingly, if I write the methods methods manually, the test is working as expected.

Could you please help me with any error in my code or this is expected behavior?
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a type hint for the `driver` attribute of the `TestDemo` class:

```python
from typing import ClassVar
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome


class TestDemo:
    driver: ClassVar[Chrome]

    def test_e2e(self, setup):
        ...
```

Sure, this won't be compatible with the static type checkers like `mypy` (if you use one for typing tests) since the `selenium` library is not typed itself, but should be just enough for the IDEs to pick up the code suggestions.

#### Edit:

Introducing `ClassVar` type hints works with Visual Studio Code and Wing IDE, but sadly not with PyCharm yet as it lacks full support for PEP 526, see [PY-20811](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-20811)). To get code completions with PyCharm, resort to using type hints for instance attributes:

```python
from typing import ClassVar
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome


class TestDemo:
    driver: Chrome

    def test_e2e(self, setup):
        ...
```

Comment: Sorry to say, this is not working. I continue to see no method after adding your suggestion.

Comment: @PrabodhGhosh you're right - looks like PyCharm doesn't support PEP 526 and specifically `ClassVar`s yet (for reference: [PY-20811](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-20811)). The workaround is to remove `ClassVar` and make `driver` to an instance attribute, see the updated snippet in the answer